# How to make a pull request to other repository from my fork?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have created a fork from a repository.

I cloned it, made changes and pushed them to my forked repository.

Now I want to merge my changes to the original repository (to which I have no permissions to edit). How do I do that? It's a pull request, right? But how do I "direct" it from my forked repo?

Comment: Indeed it's a pull request. You simply need to change the base repository on your PR to the original repository.

Answer (score 0):

Create a branch in your forked repository, name it after the issue you're trying to solve (usually there's a naming guide in the parent open source project readme).

Push the branch to your Github fork and shortly after visit your repo page on Github using the browser. The button to create a pull request will appear.

You can later push more commits or even push force. The pull request associated with the branch will automatically advance to the new HEAD.